# Joined Report Chart Not Available to Put on Page Layout

Tags: case, salesforce-id

I have a joined report between cases & jobs (custom object) and cases & sales order (custom object) summarized on Case ID, and when I edit the Page Layout, I see other report charts but not this one. I've saved it in a folder available to users as well as system admin - me. Is there something specific for the Chart Properties to enable it to be displayed on the Case Layout?

Answer (score 0):

Only **summary and matrix reports** are available to be [added to a page layout](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_embed_pagelayout.htm&language=en_US) as a chart.